# Using C++ decltype with overloaded operator++ (preincrement)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++11, decltype

For some template typename, I want to make a typedef which is the declared return type of T::operator++() (aka T's preincrement operator).

I didn't find anything definitive online, though there are certainly some mentions of decltype with preincrement.  So I tried a few things, and the only one which really works seems like a dirty hack.  What do you think of this?

```
struct S { // dummy type to simulate a real one I have
    int operator++() { return 0; } // note: return type is not S&
    int operator++(int) { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    // this works:
    typedef decltype(++S()) T1;

    // so why doesn't this work?
    // error: lvalue required as increment operand
    // typedef decltype(++int()) T2;

    // this works, but seems dirty:
    typedef decltype(++*(int*)nullptr) T3;
    typedef decltype(++*(S*)nullptr) T4;

    // I also haven't figured out how to disambiguate this,
    // though it's moot because int::operator++ is not a thing
    // error: ‘S::operator++’ refers to a set of overloaded functions
    // typedef decltype(S::operator++) T5;
}
```

I'm using GCC 4.6.2.  I briefly tried Clang but it was no better.

Comment: FWIW you cannot do it with `decltype` on a `++` expression for getting the *declared* return type - it used to work for some C++11 drafts, but the released spec does not make this work anymore. So if you *declare* a return type `int const`, what `decltype` will give you is still `int` and not `int const`. Although beside this artificial example I'm not aware of a real difference between getting the *declared* return type and simply the type of the expression (which the released spec yields).

Comment: I can live with that.  Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The lvalueness of builtin and user-defined types differs in the case of temporaries: a temporary `int` in your example is an rvalue, but a temporary `S` is an lvalue.</strike>

Edit: Technically, all temporaries are rvalues, but operators work differently with user-defined types because they are actually regular functions in disguise. This means you can do some rather non-rvalue-like things with them, such as having an `S()` as the left-hand side of the default assignment operator!

Use [`declval`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/doc/html/declval.html) to get an lvalue or rvalue of an arbitrary type in a non-evaluated context:

```
#include <utility>

// declval<T&> yields an lvalue, declval<T> an rvalue
typedef decltype(std::declval<int&>()++) T1; // int
typedef decltype(++std::declval<int&>()) T2; // int&

typedef decltype(std::declval<S&>()++)   T3; // S
typedef decltype(++std::declval<S&>())   T4; // S&
```

Comment: That's interesting, but declval is not available on all the platforms I care about (e.g. Boost 1.45 and GCC 4.4).  I could make it myself by copy/pasting what Boost has, but then it'll be fairly long and ugly, not IMO better than `decltype(++*(S*)nullptr)`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You're definitely better off putting `* (S*) nullptr` into a function and calling that `declval`. I don't know what recent Boost does (such as workarounds), but that's essentially what it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Johannes - You are, of course, absolutely correct. `S()` is not an lvalue in the C++ standard sense (in C++11, it is a prvalue.) However, given the way member function calls work in C++, `S()` may appear in contexts that in the case of builtin types require an lvalue - most importantly, as the left-hand side of the default assignment operator.